# How can I pass in an action with different number of parameters

Tags: c#, delegates, action

Assume this MyFunction:

```
void MyFunction(Action<int, string> myAction) 
{
    //do something
}

void MyFunction(Action<int> myAction) 
{
    //do something
}
```

I want to be able to create a function with only one integer as an input and pass it to MyFunction, also one with int and string as inputs. So basically I would like to be able to pass in actions with different number of parameters. Is that possible by defining only one version of MyFunction without duplicating the code?

Comment: Why would it be useful to pass in methods with different numbers of parameters (unknown at compile time)? What are you going to do with them?

Comment: @Neel what would `T2` be when just passing in a single `int`?

Comment: @Sweeper I actually found another solution to my problem, but still curious to know if that's possible or as you mentioned, is there a use for that. I got to a point that I needed extra information to be passed to the action and do exactly some behavior in MyFunction.

Comment: @Andi If you want the exact same behaviour in `MyFunction`, what's that extra information for?

Comment: @Sweeper extra information is being used in myAction. Action is doing a different thing this time, but as long as MyFunction is concerned, it does something and returns whatever MyFunctin needs.